# Can I find different values and replace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

Can I find multiple values and replace with a value in VS2010?

- Find: "cat", "dog"
- Replace with: "animal"

Comment: Hit the "Replace all" button...

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, I hope you didn't down-vote me. It requires a regular expression to do it with one replace. The point was to avoid doing two find & replaces.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK You're missing the point of the question. The point was to replace different values with the same value. Replace cat, dog, mouse, horse, cow everywhere in code with animal in one click.

Comment: @Yatrix: The downvote wasn't me, although frankly I think it's warranted.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths How nice for you. Fortunately for me, there are actual helpful people on this site that don't just type snarky (and wrong) answers in the comments section and are actually interested in answering questions in a useful manner. Then again, with that pic, what did I expect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular epxressions in the "Quick Replace" window of Visual Studio:

1. Press Ctrl+H. The "Quick Replace" window opens
2. Expand Find Options.
3. Select "Use: Regular Expressions"
4. Put `cat|dog` in the "Find what" text box, and put `animal` in the "Replace with" text box

Answer (score 1):

You can use | operator like `cat|dog` in search box.

More information at [The Visual Studio IDE and Regular Expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html)